# error in opening child window with window.open c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, href, childwindow

I have a asp.net project and Im trying to link a button to new child window but I am getting this error message "content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page."

aspx code;

```
    <a href="#" onClick="javascript:window.open('BelgeKayit.aspx','BelgeKayit','height=400,width=400'); return false;" target="_blank">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBelgeEkle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/BelgeEkle1.png"  PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("ID","~/Modul/BelgeKayit.aspx?Id={0}")%>' ToolTip="Belge Ekle" AlternateText="Belge Ekle" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' Width="25" Height="25" />
     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Remove `return false`

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:window.open('BelgeKayit.aspx','BelgeKayit','height=400,width=400');" target="_blank">
```

Comment: I already tryed that, and when ı do that ı also lose the main page which ı want it to run after opening the child page.

Comment: @amadeus you can use FireBug for Debugging

Comment: I couldnt find anything, I used firebug and it looked okey @Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: @amadeus just paste this in your browser `javascript:window.open('https://www.google.co.in','ganesh','height=400,width=400');` this works for me

Comment: that also works for me, maybe the problem is about the aspx file Im trying to open with href. But what could be the problem?? @Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: @amadeus can you post rendered html in your browser for that anchor??

Comment: no ı cant open that file alone either. ı think that file is the problem @Ganesh_Devlekar